# REST Api to get cart of anonymous user

Tags: magento2, cart, api, rest-api

As you know you can add products to the cart even if you're not logged in.

I need to retrieve what a user has added to the cart in a given browsing session. Then i need to edit it (add/remove to/from cart).

Are there APIs to do this, maybe by utilizing the session id stored in cookies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't store Quote Id in session or in Local Storage. During checkout the quote id available with `window.checkoutConfig.quoteId`.

The data is coming from `\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider`

If you want to pass quest cart from front to cookie or something else you can use following logic

```php
// instances
$quoteIdMaskFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory');
$checkoutSession = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');

$quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();

if (!$quote->getCustomer()->getId()) {
    $quoteIdMask = $quoteIdMaskFactory->create()
        ->load($quote->getId(), 'quote_id')
        ->getMaskedId();
}
```

If you want to create guest quote with API you can call

```
POST <host>/rest/<store_core_or_all>/V1/guest-carts
```

Manage Cart Items

```
-- List items that are assigned to a specified cart.
GET ​<host>/rest/<store_core_or_all>/V1​/guest-carts​/{cartId}​/items

--- Add/update the specified cart item.
POST <host>/rest/<store_core_or_all>​/V1​/guest-carts​/{cartId}​/items

--- Add/update the specified cart item.
PUT <host>/rest/<store_core_or_all>​/V1​/guest-carts​/{cartId}​/items​/{itemId}

-- Remove the specified item from the specified cart.
DELETE <host>/rest/<store_core_or_all>​/V1​/guest-carts​/{cartId}​/items​/{itemId}
```

References:

- [Create a quote](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-quote/)
- [Add items to the cart](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items/)